# I'm trying to make a Zeta converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mppt

I tried to design Zeta converter to be used in an MPPT charge controller.

V<sub>IN</sub>: 10-22 V
I<sub>IN</sub>: 3 A
F<sub>s</sub>: 30 kHz

I have  a problem.

With my design, the voltage is not coming out so well and nothing changes if I change the duty cycle (in real, not simulation, I have made a prototype.)

[image: Design 1]

I tried simulating in software with Multisim 14.3 and it works. I found out that if I send PWM to the gate with high voltage is 23 V and a low voltage is -23 V, it will work like Zeta converter.

Is it possible to do that?

[image: Design 2]

Here is a link to the simulation video:

[Link to the video](https://youtu.be/mPJdf07Ahpk)

Edited:

I have tried with isolated supply, but this was happend
[image: Updated Schematic]

[Link to video](https://youtu.be/C7F1ZsP1o2A)

So, when i turn on my supply for the converter, the supply voltage become not stable as you can see in the video also 0 Vout from converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the note I added to one of your pictures: -

[image]

> *With my design, the voltage is not coming out so well and nothing
> changes if I change the duty cycle*

Given Q1's source (output) is shorted to ground, that's all you can expect. U1 needs to run from a floating supply like from an isolated DC-to-DC converter.

> *Edited: I have tried with isolated supply, but this was happend*

[image]

That won't work. In effect you are shorting the green node to the positive terminal of battery B2 and, you are shorting the orange node to +23 volts.

Just use a regular 0 volt / ground symbol connected to the negative terminal of B1 and ditch the 0 volt / ground symbol on the  negative end of B2

Comment: Yeah I have tried to disconnect GND from VEE (pin 5) of HCPL-3120, but no voltage came out from that IC to the gate.

Comment: @tabun no it wouldn't; you need to power U1 from an isolating dc converter (as I have recently mentioned in my answer).

Comment: So how about the GND sir? If like I use Another Battery to power U1, should I connect Battery GND & Zeta Converter GND together? Or Leave it apart and connect VEE (GND of U1) to the source? I need your advice

Comment: Gnd of U1 connects to the source.

Comment: I’ve tried this one too sir. I was using different supply for U1, + from battery connected to VCC of U1, but the - of battery was not connected to Gnd of u1 either converter

Comment: You are going to have to draw a schematic so I can follow what you are saying @tabun

Comment: But no voltage was coming out from vo of U1, if the u1 GND not connected to the (-) of battery

Comment: Sorry, Made you confused. Okay i’ll draw that soon

Comment: Which battery are you talking about... draw the circuit please.

Comment: I have edited the post, please check it

Comment: @tabun see my answer edit

Comment: Sorry, the number of the GND is just the label to split them, like it's for a 15V supply. I didn't simulate it yet but did test it in actuality with my prototype like in the video

Comment: You can only have one ground. Remove the GND symbol associated with B2. I don't watch videos no matter how good folk insist that they are safe.

Comment: I upload the video to Youtube soo, yeah.

Comment: What do you mean to only have one ground sir? Should i connect the (-) of B2 to same GND to B1?

Comment: *Should i connect the (-) of B2 to same GND to B1?* <-- no because that shorts the source of the MOSFET to the negative terminal of B1.

Comment: Okay i have update the schematic again sir. Please review it. Also, what I was talking about is like this schematic. I made prototype like the last schematic and the supply for converter was so wrong, that's why i recorded it because i don't know how to explain it .

Comment: I'm not watching a video, sorry.

Comment: Can you please review my last updated schematic sir?

Comment: It looks OK but you still have problems that you report. I don't know what those problems are because I don't watch videos.

Comment: I'm using 2 AC-DC adaptor from old TV, One is giving 15V output and the other one is giving 19V output. I'm using 15V to supply the gate driver and 19V to supply the converter. Is it  wrong to use this adaptor to test?

Comment: I'm sorry but, I don't think I can help on this any more. Two adapters should be OK.